# What term types actually work with Tmux and AWS SSM? Split terminals don't show the dividers

Tags: tmux

I've been battling a pretty annoying issue lately when using AWS Systems Manager (SSM) and Tmux. When I split the terminal, the dividers disappear and the screen gets very whacky. For example, the side that is not in focus will randomly disappear, its text will cross over the dividers, all kinds of issues.

For example:

[image]

This is actually a tmux session that is split vertically. The `TERM` variable is currently set (by default) to `xterm-256color`. If I try `ansi`, then it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it now has a bunch of question marks down the divider, as if there's some character that's not supported.

How do I fix this? What term or Tmux settings do I need to set in order to have a normal Tmux experience? I am using iTerm2 for Mac and the *Source Code Pro for Powerline* font. I've tried using other fonts as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by modifying my SSM preferences to run this on every AWS SSM connection that I establish:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; export TERM=ansi
```

Comment: The comment at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2535#issuecomment-761675504 also suggests that `TERM=ansi` works, but I've been unable to get this to solve the issue. I've confirmed `LANG` is already set to `en_US.UTF-8` too, and trying different values for `TERM` does cause _some_ difference (eg. colours disappearing) so I know I'm at least setting it properly...

Comment: Thank you for sharing! working like a charm